# ring an alarm even when ringer is muted in android

Tags: android, alarm

sir, is it possible to ring an alarm even when ringer is muted? if yes, how. and also, can i set its volume to something in between and not just maxvolume? thanks in advance

```
for (SmsMessage msg : messages) {
        if (msg.getMessageBody().contains("firealert")) {

            Uri alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
             if(alert == null){
                 // alert is null, using backup
                 alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                 if(alert == null){  
                     // alert backup is null, using 2nd backup
                     alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);               
                 }
             }
             Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context.getApplicationContext(), alert);
             AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
             int maxVolumeAlarm = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
             int maxVolumeRing = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
             audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, maxVolumeAlarm,AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
             audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, maxVolumeRing,AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
             r.play();
                Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "alarm started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }//end if
    }//end for
```

Comment: "is it possible to ring an alarm even when ringer is muted?" If the user chose to mute the volume on their phone, you shouldn't try to override their wishes. Instead create an interface in your app that allows the user to mute all other notifications except yours when _they decide_ to turn this particular feature on. (I use a similar method every night.)

Comment: lol, i just thought that it would be possible

Comment: Some vendors do not mute alarms even if the ringer mode is set to silent/vibrate. It's up to the vendor to decide, so I doubt that you'll get the same behavior across all Android devices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Things to look at:

AudioManager.getRingerMode / setRingerMode.  Set it to RINGER_MODE_NORMAL to ensure the phone isn't muted or set to vibrate.  (Although you might want to check the state first, so you can store it and reset the value after your alarm is cleared.)

```
if ( aManager.getRingerMode() != AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL )
    aManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
```

If you want to set volume to 50% then check AudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume and then divide that by 2, for example.  It would probably be better to let the user configure it, though.  Use a SeekBar to have him set a preferred volume (which, again, you could reset back to normal after your alarm plays).

```
RingerVolumeBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
RingerVolumeBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener()
{
   @Override
   public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar,
                        int progress, boolean fromUser)
   {
   aManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING,
                            progress, AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
   // record new setting so you can load it up or reset it back later
   ...
   }
});
```

Comment: thanks, i've used setRingerMode() and it solved the problem. thanks again.

Comment: Is there a way to listen for events on the system volume seekbar so that I can continue to use setVolumeControlStream(), setting ringer to on when the user wants to set the volume?

Comment: I think so. Look into <action android:name="android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION"/>

I believe you can make a broadcast receiver for that.